# Print on Scala in Intellij and in ScalaFiddle

Tags: scala

I am new in Scala. I try to repeat code from scaladocs.
I write

```scala
println(1 + 1)
```

and i cant run it.
But in ScalaFiddle (https://scalafiddle.io/) it works.
In other tutorial, i have to write

```scala
object ScalaApp{
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(1 + 1)
  }
}
```

and it works for me in Intellij.
What the difference?

Comment: I am not completely sure what is the question. But I believe that the problem is that **ScalaFiddle** as well as the `scala` command that you can run on any shell, are **REPLs** _(like the Python one)_. Thus, they will evaluate each line independently. On the other hand, on **intellij**, you are on a project mode _(not a formal expression, but I guess it make sense)_. Thus, you need all the structure of any normal Scala app, that means some main method to start with.

Comment: yeah, but if i write in file Main.java : System.out.println(); it wont run without psvm
why then in scala shell i can run println, but in Intellij i cant drop that and write just println?)

Comment: As I said, because they are completely different. The **RELP** is a program that evaluates single expressions. **IntllIj** is a program that will call the **compiler** that will compile the file. As such, you need to satisfy the grammar of the language. And as for Scala `2` the only top level declarations are classes, objects, traits and packages _(as will with imports)_. - PS: Since Java 10 or 11 they have also have a **REPL** where _(I believe, I haven't used it )_ you can just `System.out.println("Hello, World!");` without any problems.

Comment: If you want to do fast tests, in Intellij you can also create a `Scala Worksheet` rather than a `Scala class`, and write code in it directly, witout creating a main class. For example you can write `print("Hello world")` only and run it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install IntelliJ's scala plugin?
If not, steps are detailled here : https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-and-test-scala.html

Comment: Of course i did. Settings -> plugins -> Scala(even first in search list) -> installed.
Start with sbt, Lightbend Project Starter, IDEA, Play 2.x (dunno what does this things mean) as i understood sdt is like Maven

Answer (score 0):

On Unix you can also run simple scala programs using a [shabang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)#Syntax).  For example with your code in `test.sh` you can

```
bash-3.2$ cat test.sh
#!/usr/bin/env scala
object ScalaApp{
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(1 + 1)
  }
}
bash-3.2$ chmod +x test.sh
bash-3.2$ ./test.sh 
2
```